# Addon executes only after left click on window

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, fcurves

I have written a script that interpolates the beginning and end keyframes of an animation intended to be cyclic in response to my own question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47116/interpolation-of-animation-cycle-extremes/).

The addon executes just fine, but only after clicking in the Fcurve window. I mean, I select, in the fcurve window, some keyframe or keyframe range or keyframe set (the script will look for the underlying channel or curve selected), then I click in my addon within its menu and finally left-click on an empty space in the window for the script to render on.

So, how could I set or fix the script so that it executes when I click on it in the menu?

The code is in [Github](https://github.com/aravergar/aravergar-blender-addons/blob/master/cyclic_animation_interpolation/cyclic_animation_interpolation.py).

PS: I don't know if the preferred behavior is posting the whole code here or referring it by a link, sorry.